# Bootstrap-datetimepicker inside <table/> not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) inside a `<table/>` and it works perfectly in some rows, however in the last rows the datetimepicker popup doesn't show in the right place where it should be.

Here's an image that illustrates the problem

[image]

And here's **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znLmpgz7/)** where you can try it out.

Comment: you have to customize the style (css)

Comment: Or, change the appearance position of datetimepicker. The datetimepicker widget needs space.

Comment: Try wrapping the datetimepicker iniside a inlin-block or block element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apply `position:relative` to the `<td>` of your table. will solve your issue.
Here's  updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/znLmpgz7/1/

```
.table td{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way, we can use this feature with jQuery 3.1? This is because my main HTML page uses jQuery 3.1 and i cannot changed it

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow you can use it with jQuery 3.1, it should not be a problem, anyways, let me create another fiddle to verify it. You can upvote my answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow unfortunately, it doesn’t work directly, you must switch to bootstrap 4 and then switch to datetimepicker for bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by adding position:relative; rule to .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget class in bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js. and i also have some top position issue so i just set "top:0px !important" in css.